# Heroku deploy: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am deploying a MERN stack app through Heroku and I'm unable to load the app due to a websocket error. Here is the link to [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/rise-and-shane93/weather-gifs).

Comment: Follow this answer link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59360740/11247828), It solves the issue